# Can Content-length header be exploited?

Tags: http, header, content-length

I have a rather simple question, so `Content-Length` is usually set to `<calculated when request is sent>` in postman.

I tried sending `Content-Length: <some_numerical_value>` and it is now taking forever.

I want to know is this a bug that can be exploited further to do DOS attack, or it is just some HTTP stuff.

What I mean to say: Is server getting busy in this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be exploited.
Server will keep on waiting for client to send more data and will cancel it based on configured timeout

https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/http-post-denial-service/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)